# How to display objects without duplicate headers?

Tags: reactjs

Please help me establish a connection between two json files, I have two json, in the first - companies, in the second - elements belonging to these companies

```
  const company = [
    {
      id: 1,
      company: "Apple"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      company: "Xiaomi"
    }
  ];

  const device = [
    {
      id: 1,
      device: "iPhone"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      device: "Xiaomi redmi 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      device: "Xiaomi redmi mi a1"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      device: "macBook pro"
    }
  ];

  const onHandleGetData = () => {
    return company.map(i => {
      const result =  device.filter(item => item.id === i.id);
      result.map(i => {
        return (
          <div>
            <strong>{i.company}</strong>
            <span>{i.device}</span>
          </div>
        )
      })
    });
  };
```

[image]

Now everything is displayed correctly, but each time the title is repeated, how to get rid of it, so that it is like in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two combined like below:

```
const data = company.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  device: device.filter(y => x.id === y.id).map(z => z.device)
}));
return (
  <div className="App">
    {data.map(item => (
      <div>
        <strong>{item.company}</strong>
        {item.device.map(unit => (
          <div>{unit}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Try it here:

```js
const App = () => {
const company = [
  {
    id: 1,
    company: "Apple"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Xiaomi"
  }
];

const device = [
  {
    id: 1,
    device: "iPhone"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    device: "Xiaomi redmi 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    device: "Xiaomi redmi mi a1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    device: "macBook pro"
  }
];
const data = company.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  device: device.filter(y => x.id === y.id).map(z => z.device)
}));
return (
  <div className="App">
    {data.map(item => (
      <div>
        <strong>{item.company}</strong>
        {item.device.map(unit => (
          <div>{unit}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar requirement. However, I can display max 4 units(from above example) in one column. For ex- I can display max 4 devices in one column. If the devices are more than 4 for a company, I should display it in another column else display in same column. Is it possible to achieve that with the above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```js
const result = company.map(company => {
  return ({
    ...company,
    devices: device.filter(dev => dev.id === company.id),
  });
});

console.log(result);

/*
0: {id: 1, company: "Apple", devices: {…}}
1: {id: 2, company: "Xiaomi", devices: {…}}
*/
```

One more way, optimized (less loop iterations and less object creations):

```js
const resultObj = device.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (acc[val.id]) {
    acc[val.id].devices.push(val);
  } else {
    acc[val.id] = {
      ...company.find(item => item.id === val.id),
      devices: [val],
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(resultObj);
console.log(result);
/*
0: {id: 1, company: "Apple", devices: {…}}
1: {id: 2, company: "Xiaomi", devices: {…}}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one could speed up and helps anyone..

```
const getProducts = () => {  
    /* products initialize */
    const result = {};

    /* populate company */
    company.forEach((item) => { result[item.id] = { company: item.company, devices: [] } });

    /* populate devices */
    device.forEach((item) => { result[item.id].devices.push(item.device) });

    return result;
};

/* data handle event */
const onHandleGetData = () => {
    const products = getProducts();
    return (
        {Object.keys(products).map(key => (
            <div>
                <strong>{products[key].company}</strong>
               {products[key].devices.map(device => (
                    <div>{device}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))}
    );
};

/*
  products:
  { 1: { company: "Apple", devices: [..., "OO7"] },
    2: { company: "Xiaomi", devices: [...] } }
  */
```